# How can I give App Annie access to only my Google Play data?

Tags: business-intelligence, appannie

When I connected my Apple account to App Annie, I created a new Email address (actually just a simple forward email from my domain) attached to an Apple account which has access to sales data only - and gave that account login to App Annie.
When I connected my Amazon account to App Annie, Amazon can create a special access key to my App data which I give to App Annie.
Both of those solutions are reasonable and straightforward.

When I try to connect my account to Google Play, App Annie needs my google account password !! To me, this seems completely unreasonable. I would like to give App Annie access to just the sales data, not my entire Google Account. Whether App Annie is trustworthy is not even the point - companies get hacked all the time these days (for example InstaAgent).

Answer (score 6):

Here are the steps to give App Annie access to Google Play sales data only :

1. Create a new google email account. *Note: You cannot just use a simple email forwarder because google will only allow you to connect google accounts to your play store data.*
   I found this step to be exceptionally difficult - constantly getting the error "You can't create a Google Account right now. Try again later".
   I tried all of these things :
   [Gmail Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/VWz0JagEwjo)
   I kept coming back to try every few hours.
   Eventually I was allowed to create an account (must be verified by mobile phone number).
2. Add a new user in Google Play in "Users & Permissions". Use your newly created Gmail account to make a new account with the permissions "View  app information" & "View Financial Data".
   Validate the new google play account from the new Gmail accounts email.
3. Log into App Annie in the same browser as you have your new gmail account created in.
   In App Annie - under "My Connections" choose "Add New Account"
   Log into gmail and give app annie the password to your newly created gmail account.